# Download PDF for SDK < 29

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, sdk

I'm developing an Android App, and I have the following problem.

I want to download a PDF so I have this code:

```
        ContentResolver resolver = getContext().getContentResolver();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            this.uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY), contentValues);
        } else {
            this.uri = resolver.insert(Uri.parse("\"content://download\""), contentValues);

    }
```

Here is the code where I download the PDF and try to open with intent.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(getContext().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "rw").getFileDescriptor());
                            fos.write(responseBody);
                            fos.flush();
                            fos.close();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                            startActivity(intent);
```

When I use a mobile with SDK < 29 it breaks down the app.

This is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:theme="@style/Theme"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="app.provider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Could anyone help me please?
Thank you! :)

Comment: What is 'resolver'? And i see no download code. What are you doing?

Comment: Please post the relevant logcat lines.

Comment: @blackapps I actualized the code where I download the pdf

Comment: ??? Why would ACTION_VIEW download pdf? The user has to select an app if you use that action.

Comment: @blackapps so what is the better solution? Sorry I'm learning with that...

Comment: "When I use a mobile with SDK < 29 it breaks down the app" -- I do not know where you got `Uri.parse("\"content://download\"")` from. On older Android versions, download to a file. See [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/master/ConferenceVideos), where I download to a file or to `MediaStore` based on API level.